# Cannot create table. SQL Error 02270

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is the table I am trying to create. However, I get the error

> SQL Error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

SQL:

```
create table Meets_In
(
    cid char(20),
    rno integer,
    time char(20),
    CONSTRAINT PRIM_KEY PRIMARY KEY(time),
    constraint meets_fk1 foreign key(cid) references COURSES(CID),
    constraint meets_fk2 foreign key(rno) references ROOMS(RNO)
);
```

These are the parent tables:

```
create table Courses
(
    cid char(20),
    cname char(20),
    credits integer,
    constraint CoursesKey Primary Key (cid, cname)
);

CREATE TABLE ROOMS 
(
    rno INTEGER,
    address CHAR(20),
    capacity INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT room_key PRIMARY KEY(rno)
);
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: Could be because `time` is a reserved word in (some versions of) SQL. You could try renaming it.

Comment: Tried it, and it did not work. I get the same error.

Comment: Why do you need to include `cname` in the primary key to table `courses`? Isn't `cid` a unique identifier already? (And if it isn't, why not?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cause

The ORA-2270, as the error message suggests, happens when there is `no matching unique or primary key for this column-list`. This could be because

- the parent lacks a constraint altogether
- the parent table's constraint is a compound key and we haven't referenced all the columns in the foreign key statement.

Now in your `COURSES` table, `CID` is not a `primary key`. It is a combination of `cid,cname`. So for every `cid`, there can be multiple rows.

Now when you reference `cid` as foreign key for `meets_in`, it will not work as it violates the second point as I mentioned above.

> Workaround

Add column `cname` in your `meets_in` table as well. Then use it like below.

```
create table Meets_In
(
    cid char(20) not null,
        cname char(20),
    rno integer not null,
    time1 char(20) not null,
    CONSTRAINT PRIM_KEY PRIMARY KEY(time1),
    constraint meets_fk1 foreign key(cid,cname) references COURSES (cid,cname), /*Added cid,cname */
    constraint meets_fk2 foreign key(rno) references ROOMS (RNO)
);
```

Comment: So how would I go about referencing `cid, cname` in the table `Meet_in` if I only need `cid`? Is this possible?

Comment: Why does `cname` not have `not null` in it?

Comment: methinks the better workaround is to remove `cname` from the PK - `cid` alone should suffice. If it doesn't, that's a separate problem that should be corrected.

Comment: you can add it to be safe. But it can work without mentioning it explicitly.

Comment: @RomanLopez - As @mathguy suggested, can you check if you can remove `cname` as primary key from `courses` table?

Comment: I removed `cname` from being a primary key, and made it `UNIQUE` since I still needed to reference it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

`Meets_In` is acting as an associative table. Therefore its primary key should include the foreign keys into the tables it is associating.

Try a primary key consisting of: `cid`, `cname`, `rno` and `time`.

As others have noted, your primary key for `courses` is `(cid, cname)`, so you also need to include both of these in your foreign key constraint `meets_fk1`. Or, if possible, ensure that `cid` only is the primary key on `courses`.

(I think `time` may be a reserved word, so perhaps consider renaming it.)

Comment: `time` is not a reserved word in Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b31231/appb.htm  Generally though that is a good concern to always have in mind.